# df['Column'].mean() returning nan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I've created multiple dataframes with essentially the same information, and I need to calculate the mean of one specific column. I'm using this code `df.loc['Total', 'Column']= df['Column'].mean()` which has worked my first few dataframes and typically returns the equivalent of:

```
0        1.000000e+02
1        1.000000e+02
2        1.000000e+02
3        1.000000e+02
4        1.000000e+02
             ...     
84957    1.000000e+02
84958    1.000000e+02
84959    1.000000e+02
Total    1.002251e+02
Name: Column, Length: 84961, dtype: float64
```

However, I've just run into a dataset that has at least one `NaN` value in the column and the mean function doesn't appear to be working and is returning `NaN` as the mean, as seen below.

```
1         71.111111
2               NaN
3         68.888889
4         68.181818
5         68.181818
            ...    
84957    244.444444
84958    244.444444
84959    233.333333
84960    237.500000
Total           NaN
Name: Column, Length: 84961, dtype: float64
```

I don't know why it is returning `NaN`, the only clear difference I can spot between this dataframe and the other is the presence of an `NaN` value.  When I create a simple dataframe with only 5 rows and have a single `NaN` the mean is correctly calculated. Any help as to why and how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For me it working correct

Comment: If use `print (df['Column'].mean())` it return `NaN` for second sample?

Comment: I'm still getting `nan` when adding in `print()`

Comment: If use `print (df['Column'].dtypes)` it is float?

Comment: Yep, I get `float64`

Comment: I would say the problem is not related to a nan value, which should be handled correctly by `mean`. Are you sure there are not others strange values in your dataframe?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've found the answer to my question, I had `inf` values hiding in my data set (it's hard to manually trawl through almost 85,000 data points), converting them to `nan`'s appears to have fixed it - Thanks for your help!